# how to call a method without calling its subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I've been playing around with Inheritance and Polymorphism. The print out of the code below is: Student 1 Person 1 Undergrad 2. So I have two questions:

Why does Java automatically insert a .this when I call method2() in the student class? What if instead of the original print out, I wanted to print out Student 1 Person 1 Student 2. How would I explicitly call method2 of the Student class?

I have 3 classes, the Person class:

```
public class Person {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person u = new Undergrad();
    u.method1();
  }
  public void method1() {
    System.out.print("Person 1 ");
  }
  public void method2(){
    System.out.print("Person 2 ");
  }   
}
```

The student class

```
public class Student extends Person {
  public void method1(){
    System.out.print("Student 1 ");
    super.method1();
    method2();
  }
  public void method2(){
    System.out.print("Student 2");
  }
}
```

And the Undergrad class:

```
public class Undergrad extends Student{
  public void method2(){
    System.out.print("Undergrad 2 ");
  }
}
```

Comment: You have overridden the `method2` in `Undergrad` and cll it on an object of the `Undergrad` class. So the overridden `method2` is called because that is the whole point of polymophism. If you want that overridden method to call methods of its superclasses you have to program it into the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the code works:

1. You create an `Undergrad` called `u`.
2. You call `u.method1()`
3. `Undergrad` doesn't define `method2`, so it looks at its parent.
4. `Student` defines `method2`, so it is called.
5. `"Student 1 "` is printed
6. `Student::method1` calls `super.method1`, which looks at `Person`
7. `"Person 1 "` is printed; the function returns to the stack point at 6
8. `Student::method1` calls `method2`
9. Keep in mind that this is technically referring to the `Undergrad` object. Since `Undergrad` overrides `method2`, it prints `Undergrad 2`.
10. `method2` returns back to `main`

If you want to call `method2` of a Student class, you'll need to find a `Student` object that doesn't override `method2`; that is, an actual normal student, not an undergrad.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into the all keywords such as public, final, private, static. Then there are the topics of "method hiding" and "method overriding". Also look into the '@override annotation'. Try to understand how you can cast classes. Besides the other answers in this topic, in your example you can also do:

```
Student u = new Undergrad();
```

because any instance of Undergrad is also a Student. However now you have access to the methods of Student. So I'd suggest making method2 inside Student private so u.method2() prints "Student 2".